Order of adding ice-candidates to webrtc-connection
MDN documentation for RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate() says that it returns a promise.
So an ice-candidate will likely is being processed yet when this methods returns.
I get several ice-candidates from a remote and do not wait - whether addIceCandidate() gets resolved or not.
The question is: should I necessarily wait when the previous promise p = addIceCandidate will be rejected or resolved ? Or it doesn't matter ?

The order does not matter, this operation is serialized in the operations queue:
https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-peerconnection-addicecandidate
Errors from addIceCandidate should be extremly rare but you should monitor them nonetheless. One example of an error is trying to add a candidate when there is not remote description.

Philipp, thank you very much! As regards this: "One example of an error is trying to add a candidate when there is not remote description." Local peer can't control an order of remote peer send 1-candidates, 2-it's (remote) offer or vice versa. Does it mean that if local gets candidates before the offer, it should accumulate them (candidates) until remote offer will be received, and only after that call addIceCandidate ?

in that case you should fix the remote peer, it is sending the events in the wrong order.

Philipp, may be remote should not send it's candidate at all ? Why are they needed if SDP (createOfffer) from the remote will include this information ?

https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/ explains the whole process of trickle-ice and why it is an optimization.
